# Continuity of function in higher dimensions

Tags: analysis, functions

Assume $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g:F\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then if I define $h:E\times F \to\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ then is $h$ continuous on $E\times F$? (I believe this is true and I do have an idea on how to prove it)

If I define $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ then is $h$ continuous on $E\times F$? (I have no idea on how to prove or disprove this one)

Comment: You may want to look into topological vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to define the right topology on the product $X\times Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces). This topology is given by the projections $p$ (resp. $q$) from $X\times Y$ to $X$ (resp. $Y$). It is the coarsest topology on $X\times Y$ that makes the projections continuous. It is called product topology if you want to look it up.

So by definition of the product topology, the projections are continuous. So (letting $p$ be the projection on $E$ and $q$ the one on $F$ with your notations) we have that : $h = f\circ p + g\circ q $.
The last thing you need to conclude is that addition (or multiplication for your second question) are continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then $h$ will only be a composition of continuous functions and as such it will be continuous.

Maybe try to prove the continuity of addition and multiplication by yourself, which is easier since you are more familiar with the domain of the maps (here $\mathbb{R}^2$).